# StringBuilder.Remove() Function works unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a short code that takes in a string, and outputs it as a formatted phone number.

The code looks like that:

```
    public static void Main()
{
    {
        StringBuilder phoneNumber = new StringBuilder("(559) 440-9safa071",20);

        string enteredPhoneNumber = "(559) 440-9safa071";
        for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.Length-1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing: " + phoneNumber[i]);
            if (phoneNumber[i] == ' ' || Char.IsWhiteSpace(phoneNumber[i]))
            {
                phoneNumber.Remove(i, 1);
            }
            else if (char.IsNumber(phoneNumber[i]) == false)
            {
                phoneNumber.Remove(i, 1);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Entered Phone Number:" + enteredPhoneNumber + "\n " + phoneNumber);

    }
}
```

For some reason, I cannot get the space between the 559 and the 440 removed, as well as some letters seem to get removed while others not.

This is the output:

```
Testing: (
Testing: 5
Testing: 9
Testing: )
Testing: 4
Testing: 4
Testing: 0
Testing: -
Testing: s
Testing: f
Testing: 0
Testing: 7
Entered Phone Number:(559) 440-9071
 559 4409aa071
```

I have spent around an hour trying to tinker, change keywords, even trying an online compiler to check if my Visual Studio is acting up, but I cannot find the solution.

Comment: Your problem is surely that you remove a character at `i`, meaning that the next character becomes the new character at `i`, but then you increment `i` anyway, thus skipping over the next character?

Comment: You need a while-loop.  Or for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.Length; ) and increment i when needed.

Comment: Or do `i--;` when you remove the character (so you can keep your `for` loop looking "normal").

Comment: What is the desired output? Just the digits and letters without the parentheses, dashes, and spaces?

Comment: You could just do `var phoneNumber = new string(enteredPhoneNumber.Where(char.IsNumber).ToArray());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of the StringBuilder gets modified while you process it.

That is, if you remove a character and do `i++`, it will skip over one character.

There are several options, many of them quite hard to read. Immediate solution: remove `i++` in the for loop and only increase when you don't remove a character, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.Length-1;)         // <-- removed i++
{
    Console.WriteLine("Testing: " + phoneNumber[i]);
    if (phoneNumber[i] == ' ' || Char.IsWhiteSpace(phoneNumber[i]))
    {
        phoneNumber.Remove(i, 1);
    }
    else if (char.IsNumber(phoneNumber[i]) == false)
    {
        phoneNumber.Remove(i, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;                                     // <-- added i++
    }
}
```

A more readable approach would be to store the result in a new variable:

```
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.Length-1;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Testing: " + phoneNumber[i]);
    if (phoneNumber[i] != ' ' &&
        !Char.IsWhiteSpace(phoneNumber[i]) &&
        char.IsNumber(phoneNumber[i]))
    {
        result += phoneNumber[i];
    }
}
```

This reveals an obvious optimization of the condition:

```
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.Length-1;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Testing: " + phoneNumber[i]);
    if (char.IsNumber(phoneNumber[i]))
    {
        result += phoneNumber[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use a `StringBuilder` for `result`, rather than using repeated string concatenation

Comment: @canton7: for a phone number? Without measuring the performance impact, I consider that premature optimization.

Comment: It's more than *not* using a StringBuilder in this case is code smell: if you're doing repeated concatenation then the default should be StringBuilder, and moving to string is a premature optimization. Most reviewers would see repeated concatenation in a loop as an oversight, or lack of knowledge of the StringBuilder type

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach (using a unit test to demonstrate the correctness)?

```cs
[Fact]
public void CanGetPhoneNumber()
{
    const string enteredPhoneNumber = "(559) 440-9safa071";
    string phoneNumber = GetPhoneNumber(enteredPhoneNumber);

    Assert.Equal("5594409071", phoneNumber);
}

private static string GetPhoneNumber(string enteredPhoneNumber)
{
    var phoneNumber = new StringBuilder();

    var regex = new Regex("[0-9]+");
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(enteredPhoneNumber))
    {
        phoneNumber.Append(match.Value);
    }

    return phoneNumber.ToString();
}
```